# Fabric when register the user give error Error: Calling register endpoint failed with error [Error: unable to verify the first certificate]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am running the fabric ca using the docker container, When i enrolled the admin, It's works well, But when i am trying to register the new user, its throws the error, as shown below. I am using fabric node to enroll and register the users.

> Error: Calling register endpoint failed with error [Error: unable to
>   verify the first certificate]

docker file

```
ca0:
image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
environment:
  - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.example.com
ports:
  - "7054:7054"
command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
volumes:
  - ./fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
container_name: ca_peerOrg1
networks:
  - byfn
```

In my node connection.json

```
 "certificateAuthorities": {
    "ca.example.com": {
        "url": "https://127.0.0.1:7054",
        "caName": "ca.example.com"
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `tlsCACerts` parameter in your `connection.json` to allow your CA TLS certificate.

Comment: thank you for response. But when i enroll admin using fabric node sdk , i dont get any tlsCACerts, I have tlsCACerts generated by using cryptogen tool, do i need use it. Any example would be helpful.

Comment: You have `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED` to true, so your CA, if working, is using TLS. Your client is not going to trust any certificate, to avoid a man-in-the-middle, only those included in or signed by your `tlsaCACerts` (and maybe those in the system trust store, I'm not sure). So, trust me, you need to specify your Fabric-CA TLS certificate (or the parent CA's one if not self-signed) through `tlsCACerts`. Take a look at your CA logs, too.